# Git remote 'set-url' command changes urls of multiple folders

Tags: git, version-control

I have a folder named 'Py' where I store all my Python projects. At the beginning, everything was fine as I created project folders and set them different origin urls. Every folder inside this 'Py' folder was linked to its own Git repository.

Then, I don't know what happened, but I noticed that by changing the url in one of the subfolders, all the urls of the other subfolders in the parent folder also change. For example, I go to the 'Py/folder1' subfolder and execute

```
git remote set-url origin 'some-url'
```

Then I go to the 'Py/folder2', execute

```
git remote -v
```

And see that this subfolder's url also changed to 'some-url'. I suspect that somehow I made the whole 'Py' folder look as if it is one repository, not several of them stored in one folder. The question is how to change this behaviour.

Comment: Are the different folders in the same repo?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, apparently yes. When I execute `git remote -v` in the parent folder, it shows an url which is the same for all the subfolders. I think I need to do `git remove` in the parent folder first, and then to set urls that I need in all the subfolders  - am I right?

Comment: `git remove` is not a command.  Do you mean `git remote remove`?  If so... no, that isn't what needs to be done.  You need to sort out the local repo definitions before it's even possible to get remote configurations right.

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
.../
  parent/
    project1/
    project2/
```

and they all share a `remote` configuration, then the most likely situation is that

(1) There exists a directory `.../parent/.git` which maps `parent` and all of its subfolders as a worktree of a single repo

(2) There do not exist directories `.../parent/project1/.git` or `.../parent/project2.git`, which would map each proejct folder to its own git repo

If they previously behaved as independent repos, but not any more, then it seems that somehow the `parent/.git` directory was created (perhaps via `git init`), *and* somehow the other `.git` directories were deleted.

Quick disclaimer: I find it very unlikely that the projects' `.git` folders were accidentally removed.  The advice that follows takes the situation as presented at face value, and is therefore invalid if the observations spelled out in the question are inaccurate, or if some "little detail" has been left out.

That said... if the above indeed somehow happened, then the deletion of the `.git` directories is a significant loss of data (locally, at least).  Fortunately, git remotes can be seen as a sort of "backup" of *most* of the local data, so if you were recently in sync with each projects' remote you may be able to recover without too much hassle.

So the first thing I'd do is, leaving `parent` alone for the time being, create a new parent directory (e.g. `.../parent2`).  In that directory, create new clones of each project repo from the remote.

Next you would compare what's in each project directory under `parent2` against what's in the corresponding directory under `parent`.  (You could use `git diff`, or some other mass diff tool like Beyond Compare.)  And what you do from there depends on what you find.

If all projects are identical, then it seems you're in luck; you may be able to just wipe the old `parent` folder and move the projects from the new `parent` folder back to their original locations, and resume from there.

If there are differences, you might have to see whether you have local changes not in the remote, whether the remote has changes you didn't have locally, or both.  Local changes not in the remote may be captured within commits to the (apparently-accidental) monorepo you currently have at `parent` - in which case they could be extracted using `git filter-branch` with a `--parent-filter` and then migrated into the individual project repos to be merged in whatever way makes sense.  Or the individual changes might be lost, and you might have to just update the individual repos' states to reflect your newest changes.

And one special consideration - it may be that one (or more) of the newly-cloned copies contain the entire `parent` structure.  That could occur if, at some point, you had set the `parent` repo's URL as though it were the URL for a specific project.  Searching history might reveal a point when that happened.

None of these clean-up procedures is 100% spelled out because there's too much unknown about what you'd find from the re-cloning process, and the subsequent steps depends on what you find.